# Error jshint validation es5

Tags: javascript, macos, terminal, jshint

error throwing on jshint validation over terminal, I have empty js file still it throws error.

```
f.js: line 0, col 0, ES5 option is now set per defaul
1 error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create .jshintrc file in your home directory and set es5 to FALSE.

```
{
   "es5"           : false,     // true: Allow ES5 syntax (ex: getters and setters)
}
```